# Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post

Tags: docker, jenkins

I’ve just run Dockerfile in jenkins setup then I get the following error:

Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=2quv9npfhvxjco1lqvt8aea9h&shmsize=0&t=testfile&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
.
..
Dockerfile
WebApp.war
SSH: EXEC: completed after 404 ms
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [Docker] ...
SSH: Transferred 1 file(s)
Finished: SUCCESS

Answer (score 0):

docker.deamon tell us this:

> The Docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By
> default that Unix socket is owned by the user root and other users can
> only access it using sudo. The Docker daemon always runs as the root
> user.
>
> If you don’t want to preface the docker command with sudo, create a
> Unix group called docker and add users to it. When the Docker daemon
> starts, it creates a Unix socket accessible by members of the docker
> group.

```
Check if the docker group already exists:
cat /etc/group | grep docker

if it doesn't, create with this command:
sudo groupadd docker

add the jenkins user to docker group:
sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins-user
newgrp docker

Check if is it worked...
$ cat /etc/group | grep docker
docker:x:***:jenkins-user

Restart the jenkins

logout, and login again
```

Or you can just try run the docker with sudo.